# Database Normalization need information

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I have a view from a database

Un-normalized:

> (**CustomerID**,Firstname,Lastname,Address,City,Province,Postalcode,Prepaidtip,Routeid,Routename{PaperIDDescription,DeliveryTypeID,Deliverytypedescription,Deliverytypecurrentcharge}

1st Normal form:

> (**CustomerID**,Firstname,Lastname,Address,City,Province,Postalcode,Prepaidtip,Routeid,Routename)
>
> (**PaperIDDescription,*CustomerID***,DeliveryTypeID,Deliverytypedescription,Deliverytypecurrentcharge)

2nd Normal Form:

> Customer(**CustomerID**,Firstname,Lastname,Address,City,Province,Postalcode,Prepaidtip)
>
> Route(*CustomerID*,**PaperIddescription**,RouteID,Routename)
>
> Delivery(**PaperIDDescription**,DeliveryTypeID***,Deliverytypedescription,DeliveryTypeCurrentCharge

3rd normal Form: No changes.

- Bolded columns are primary key
- Italicized are foreign key
- Italic + Bold is both
- "{}" stand for repeating groups.

Does my normalization look right?

Comment: This is very messy, and I'm not really sure what the question is. Is it a homework assignment?

Comment: Here are two answers that may be useful for you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190581/normalization-in-database/32517139#32517139 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496508/how-far-to-take-normalization-in-database-design/32525594#32525594

Comment: You're asking us to guess your functional dependencies based on column names.  You'll get better results if you specify the FDs.  As it is, I think your Route relation doesn't look right.

Comment: how does it not look right? why would you tell me your opinion without stating the reasoning behind it? defeats the purpose..

Comment: And all the functional dependencies are listed as 0 normal form 0nf and its listed at the top...

Comment: Those aren't functional dependencies.  "Given a relation R, a set of attributes X in R is said to functionally determine another set of attributes Y, also in R, (written X → Y) if, and only if, each X value is associated with precisely one Y value; R is then said to satisfy the functional dependency X → Y." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency)