# same Column name in multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am building an e learning website. I have three types of users : novice, intermediate and expert. I have 3 tables: lecture,chapter and pages.For each of these table I have to differentiate them by adding for which type of user is that lecture,chapter and page. 
Is this a good practice to add same column name `category` (which can be either novice, intermediate or expert) **to all the 3 tables** ?

Comment: It's a find practice.  You will need to alias the tables when you select them anyway.  So, something like "name" would be "table1.name", "table2.name", etc...

Comment: so i won't be penalize for this practice. Because if i create a new table named `category` i will have only 2 fields in that just with the `ID` and `type` -(novice/inter/expert)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add more characteristics later to your user categories, the best is to create a separate table for this (eg: user_categories) and refer to this table in all 3 content tables. It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_types (id int PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE lectures (id int PRIMARY KEY, user_type int REFERENCES user_types(id));
```

You can also refer to this post to decide how to proceed in your case:[How far to take normalization in database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496508/how-far-to-take-normalization-in-database-design)