# SQL multiple foreign keys vs single foreign key on multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm trying to figure out how to define foreign keys in my database.

Let's say I have three tables:

- Site (this is the site where a company resides),
- Warehouse (on this site there can be multiple Warehouses), and
- WarehouseLocation (in that warehouse there are multiple locations, eg shelves)

Now,

- `Site-Warehouse` is a one-to-many relationship
- `Warehouse-WarehouseLocation` is a one-to-many relationship

When would I describe `WarehouseLocation` with multiple foreign keys, one to `Warehouse.id` and one to `Site.id`?

```
Site --[ Warehouse
  |         ---
  |          |
  +----[ WarehouseLocation
```

When would I just use:

```
 Site --[ Warehouse --[ WarehouseLocation
```

In the first option when I lookup a `WarehouseLocation` I would need the `Site.id` and the `Warehouse.id`.

In the second option when I lookup a `WarehouseLocation` I would need the `Warehouse.id`, but to lookup the Warehouse I would need the `Site.id`

I'm confused about which option is suitable in what situation. Can someone give me some hints of the pros and cons of both options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The second option is what you should be looking at. That is,

> A `WareHouseLocation` table  would have only the `WareHouseID` as the
>   foreign key and the `WareHouse` table would have the `SiteID` as the
>   foreign key.

**Explanation**

*You have to look at it from a functional perspective and not querying perspective.* A `WareHouseLocation` specifies the location of a `Warehouse`. Hence, the relationship makes sense(i.e. the foreign key seems appropriate). However, if you think about it, the `WarehouseLocation` really has nothing to do with the `Site`. Hence, the relationship purely from a functional perspective doesn't make a lot of sense.

However, from a querying perspective, it looks great as you would need to retrieve `SiteID` and `WareHouseID` in most, if not all situations, when querying over the `WareHouseLocation` table. Having them readily available in the same table would reduce `JOIN`s and making querying a much easier task. This seems to be the crux of your dilemma in terms of database design.

Database design is quite a complex subject and a lot of considerations go into into it, some of which are very specific to the project itself. A general rule of thumb is to keep databases as *normalized* as possible (*especially if you are reading textbooks*). In practice, however, a lot of database designers prefer to denormalize databases to an extant atleast. Normalizing/Denormalizing a database is quite an opinionated subject, so I won't delve on it here. You can read more about it in the following posts :

[How far to take normalization in database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496508/how-far-to-take-normalization-in-database-design)

[How does one know when to stop normalizing?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81548/how-does-one-know-when-to-stop-normalizing)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Allright thanks, this info and the given links should help me grasp it a bit more!